# How to access git based spring-boot configurations without config-server

Tags: git, spring-boot, spring-webflux, configserver

I would like to load spring-boot configuratons using embedded config-server without exposing the config-server rest endpoints or without inheriting the @EnableMvc so that i can use my @EnableWebFlux based controllers/handlers

According to https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/885 unresolved issue, i cannot just have both config-server and webflux active

Caused by:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The Java/XML config for Spring MVC and Spring WebFlux cannot both be enabled, e.g. via @EnableWebMvc and @EnableWebFlux, in the same application.
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
```

is raised whenever i run the code